# NSDate - Offsetting the Time Zone

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I must be missing something small her but can't figure it out. Trying to create a date for comparison, but I can't seem to offset currentDate from GMT to EST:

```
// current date (gmt) //
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeZone *currentDateTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];

NSDateFormatter *currentDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[currentDateFormat setTimeZone:currentDateTimeZone];
[currentDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];

NSString *currentDateString = [currentDateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"currentDateString: %@", currentDateString); // returns 2011-01-05 13:30:30 EST

NSDate *currentDateWithOffset = [currentDateFormat dateFromString:currentDateString];

NSLog(@"currentDateWithOffset: %@", currentDateWithOffset); // returns 2011-01-05 18:30:30 +0000
```

Thanks!

Edit:

I'm calling a method in a separate class (trying to make this portable) using the following line:

```
[Expiration expires:[[NSDate alloc] initWithString:@"2011-01-07 12:00:00 +0000"] within:1.0]
```

in the expires method, I have these lines:

```
NSComparisonResult comparison = [currentDateWithOffset compare:expires]; // check for a fixed date to disable the demo

double withinRange = [installDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDateWithOffset]; // check for number of seconds between "within" and the install date
```

I'm then comparing these two values like so:

```
if(withinRange >= within && withinRange > 0.0) {
    // app is expired //
}
else {
    // app is still enabled (so far...) //
    if(comparison == NSOrderedDescending || comparison == NSOrderedSame) {
        // app is expired //
    }
    else {
        // app is still enabled //
    }
}
```

Does this help? Thanks for your patience!

Edit:

Here's the entire expires:within method as it currently stands...

```
+(BOOL)expire:(NSDate*)expires within:(double)within {
   // default expired value //
    BOOL expired = NO;

    // convert within value from days to seconds //
    within *= 24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0;

    // current date (gmt) //
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

    // install date //
    NSDate *installDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"installDate"];

    // check for a value in installDate //
    if (nil == installDate) {
        // app is running for the first time //
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:currentDate forKey:@"installDate"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        installDate = currentDate;
    }

    if([installDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < (-within)) {
        expired = YES;
    }
    else {
        if([expires timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0) {
            expired = YES;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"installDate:%@", installDate);
    NSLog(@"expires:%@", expires);
    NSLog(@"currentDate:%@", currentDate);

    return expired; 
}
```

I'm then calling it from another class with

```
message.text = (YES == [Expiration expire:[[NSDate alloc] initWithString:@"2011-01-07 12:00:00 -0500"] within:(0.015625/2)]) ? @"This App is Expired" : @"This App is Active";
```

When running in the simulator (fresh app install), NSLog displayed this...

```
[Session started at 2011-01-06 10:43:46 -0500.]
2011-01-06 10:43:48.146 TimeBasedDemo[14717:207] installDate:2011-01-06 15:43:48 +0000
2011-01-06 10:43:48.147 TimeBasedDemo[14717:207] expires:2011-01-07 17:00:00 +0000
2011-01-06 10:43:48.147 TimeBasedDemo[14717:207] currentDate:2011-01-06 15:43:48 +0000
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to compare the current date/time against a supplied date/time for time-limited demo apps. THe part that's giving me hassle is doing the comparison in my time zone (EST) rather than GMT. Easier to use my own timezone than convert to GMT when I call the containing method.

Comment: That code looks exactly right, and so does the output. I'm guessing your problem is that you expected to see `10:43:48 -0500` in the log rather than `15:43:48 +0000`. The thing is - it's OK. They are *the same time*. That's just how it prints out when you call NSLog.

Comment: Okay, I feel like a real idiot now... NSLog is printing out expires as GMT AFTER applying the offset of -0500. I was expecting to see it as 07:00:00. I think I get it now. Thanks for all of your help. Now I just need to figure out how to get it to call this method whenever the app is being used. Thanks again!

Comment: P.S. I figured out how to get the last part how to work as well, so that saves a new thread!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `NSDate` object represents an instant in time irrespective of time zone and calendar considerations. Time zone info is relevant when you print or parse a date, but it is not stored *within* the `NSDate`.

Say you are creating your expiration date like this:

```
NSDate *exp=[[NSDate alloc] initWithString:@"2011-01-07 12:00:00 +0000"]
```

That says you want the expiration to occur at noon GMT, on the 7th Jan. If you want it to expire at noon EST, create it with -0500 instead. What you should *not* have to do is mess with the current time when you do a comparison.

An easy way just to see if the time has passed is then

```
if ([exp timeIntervalSinceNow]<0) { /* it's expired */ }
```

and you can see if `within` seconds have passed since the install date like this:

```
if ([installDate timeIntervalSinceNow]<(-within)]) { /* it's expired */}
```

Comment: Thanks, invariant! That helped clean (and clear) things up a bit, thanks. Unfortunately I'm still having a problem with the time zone issue. installDate is set using currentDate (NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];) so there's still a discrepancy during the comparison. Since the goal is to reuse the class without editing, and to allow for time zone offsets, is NSDate the way to actually go with this?

Comment: I'm sure NSDate is the right way to go, I do it this exact way myself. I think you are misunderstanding how NSDate works. If you record the install date using `[NSDate date]`, store it, then compare it later, again with `[NSDate date]` (or `timeIntervalSinceNow`), then it will always give you the elapsed time *between the moments that those methods were called*. Time zone simply doesn't come into it, it's just a notation for when you display it or store it as a string. I do the exact thing in my own code with no problems.

Comment: I guess I still don't get it. I've edited above to show the code and the results from NSLog...

Answer (score 17):

None of these answers gave me an `NSDate` object with the current, local date. So here's how I did it:

```
NSDate *currentDateWithOffset = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cocoa, `NSDate` is an abstract representation of a date with no time zone information applied. Note that `currentDateWithOffset` *is* the same date as the date string, just in a different time zone (five hours ahead). This is expected behavior, as `NSDate` does not persist the time zone used to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered around a bit more and found a way to 'cheat' the offset to suit my needs. From other reading, I'm guessing that NSCalendar might be a better long term-solution, but for now I ended up changing

```
NSDate *currentDateWithOffset = [currentDateFormat dateFromString:currentDateString];
```

to

```
NSDate *currentDateWithOffset = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ +0000", currentDateString]];
```

That got me the results I needed and works in the later comparisons I'm using. Thanks for the background info all!

Comment: You would be better to have put the effort in to creating the reference date correctly, then you wouldn't have had to swizzle the current date to get it to work.

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to do that.